# Сравнение времени mktime в php

Tags: php

```
$uFrom = 1340348400;
$uTo = 1340409600;
$time = 1340310456;
$bWork = ($uFrom <= $time and $uTo > $time) ? 1 : 0;
```

Получаем 0. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное потому, что просто `$uFrom > $time` =)

```
$bWork = ($uFrom <= $time && $uTo > $time) ? 1 : 0;
```

Данная конструкция присваивает единицу, если  `($uFrom <= $time && $uTo > $time)==true`,
а эта конструкция в свою очередь возвращает `true`, только если оба условия `is true`. В вашем случае этого не происходит. У вас получается, что `!($uFrom <= $time)==true`, т.е `($uFrom > $time)==true`. Вам следует использовать **or**, впрочем, это уже зависит от вашей задачи.

**UPD:**

```
$c = 7; // date("H");  текущее время(в часах)
for($i=1;$i<=24;$i++)  // вот демонстрация для каждого часа
{
echo $i." => ";
if($i < 4 || $i > 11) print("Open!"); else print("Close"); echo("<br>");
}
```

Допилить алгоритм до ума или написать обратный( определить,когда закрыто ), думаю, вам не составит труда.

Comment: Например, открытие в 11 утра, закрытие в 4 часа ночи. Сейчас час ночи, и объект закрыт. Потому что в mktime час ночи меньше чем 11 утра.

Comment: Ну, все верно!

---
А вам надо определить, закрыт ли объект?

Comment: Да, в час ночи он по идеи должен быть открыт. Если работает с 11 утра до 4 ночи.

Comment: Например если написать:


  echo "C ".date("H:i:s",$uFrom)."<br />";

  echo "Сейчас ".date("H:i:s",$uTime)."<br />";

  echo "По ".date("H:i:s",$uTo)."<br /><br />";

То возвратит 
C 11:00:00
Сейчас 03:00:00
По 04:00:00

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: А вы не могли бы убрать то что писали сначала и оставить только то, что необходимо) Простите, ночь, я уже запутался)

Comment: Код после "UPD" =)

Answer (score 1):

`$uFrom > $time 
1340348400 > 1340310456`